# Giving an extra id by comparing two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my transaction

```
customer_id     time_id       product_id
------------    ---------     -----------
3               345           34
3               345           45
3               345           54
7               435           23
7               435           24
7               678           65
7               678           54
```

Here my issue is I need to create a new column with unique transaction id comparing columns `customer_id` and `time_id` with AUTO_INCREMENT of `transaction_id` like below

```
transaction_id    customer_id     time_id       product_id
------------    ---------     -----------
1                 3               345           34
1                 3               345           45
1                 3               345           54
2                 7               435           23
2                 7               435           24
3                 7               678           65
3                 7               678           54
```

I have try with following query but it show me error.

```
ALTER TABLE `transaction_filter` ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT GROUP BY customer_id,time_id
```

Comment: there is no such `auto_increment group by` feature. you should create a separate transaction table.